# How to determine current SIP language on WP

Tags: windows-phone-8, internationalization

Is there a way to determine current SIP language on WP platform? I want to switch input control - for example TextBox to RTL when user chooses Hebrew language. I know that it is possible because native apps can do that and third party (foursquare) can do that with ease also.

Answer (score 1):

These apps aren't determining anything based on the "SIP language" (and you can't actually query anything about the SIP - you can only set a scope).

What they're almost certainly doing is querying `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` to determine the language that the user has set for the phone.

This is based on the assumption that this hasn't been overridden and will normally be configured on start up. Take a look at the `InitializeLanguage()` method in `App.xaml.cs` to see how this is set.

For more on adding localization to your app see [Globalization and localization for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637522%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Maybe I'll ask it another way. Please launch SMS native app or foursquere third party app. Go to any textbox and switch keyboard to Hebrew using globe icon. Please tell me how they are switching flow to RTL? This has nothing to do with current language for the phone.